# Ada loop stops after first input

Tags: ada

Hi I am currently writing a program that reads inputs from a file and determines whether or not the number is neither prime nor composite, is composite, or prime. Basically my problem is that I can not get my program to continue it stops after one input, even though I have more numbers in my file that need to be evaluated. Here is my code:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
USE Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

PROCEDURE TestPrime IS
   PACKAGE Boolean_Io IS NEW Ada.Text_Io.Enumeration_Io(Boolean);
   USE Boolean_Io;

   N       : Integer;
   X       : Natural   := 2;
   S       : Integer;
   IsPrime : Boolean   := True;
   C       : Character;
BEGIN
   WHILE NOT End_Of_File LOOP
      Excep:
         BEGIN
      Get(N);
      IF N = 0 OR N = 1 THEN
         Put_Line(N'Img & " is neither prime nor composite");
      END IF;
      LOOP
         S := N mod X;
         IF S = 0 THEN
            IsPrime := False;
         END IF;
         EXIT WHEN X = N - 1;
         X := X + 1;
      END LOOP;
      IF IsPrime = True THEN
         Put_Line(N'Img & " is prime");
      ELSE
         Put_Line(N'Img & " is composite");
      END IF;
       EXCEPTION
           WHEN Data_Error =>
              Put_Line("Data error: You must enter a number!!");
              Get(C);
       END Excep;

   END LOOP;
END TestPrime;
```

I am just asking where my program is getting stuck and why it is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: (1) How are you telling it what file to read from?  (2) What is the exact symptom: is the program exiting quietly, or are you seeing your "Data error" message or some other message, or is it hanging?  (3) Are you seeing any output about whether the first number is prime or composite?  (4) What numbers are in your input file?

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent; this might result from pasting code with tab characters. You never use your `Boolean_IO`. `IF IsPrime = True THEN` is more clearly written as `IF ISPrime THEN`. The `'Img` attribute is specific to GNAT; that doesn't mean you shouldn't use it, but it limits your code's portability to other Ada compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't described the exact symptoms (yet), I'm not sure whether this is the entire source of the problem or not.  However, the declaration

```
X : Natural := 2;
```

will initialize `X` at the beginning of the procedure *only*.  It does not reinitialize `X` every time it goes through the loop, because the declaration isn't inside the loop.  Therefore, after the program processes the first number `N`, `X` will be `N-1` when you're done.  Since you don't reinitialize it, `X` will have that same value.  Then if the second number in your file is smaller than the first one, `X` will start at a number larger than this; since you keep incrementing it by 1 and only exit the loop when it becomes equal to `[the new N] - 1`, this will be a **loooooooooooooooooooooooooong** wait.

You can just say `X := 2` at the beginning of your outer loop to reinitialize it.  Another possibility is to declare `X` as local inside the loop, instead of local to the whole procedure; something like

```
WHILE NOT End_Of_File LOOP
    Excep:
        DECLARE
            X : Natural := 2;
        BEGIN
```

and so on.

Keith's comments are worth following.  A couple other things: as a matter of practice, I would always write something like `exit when X >= N - 1;` instead of `exit when X = N - 1;`.  It shouldn't make a difference if you do things correctly, but this kind of thing can prevent hanging when something accidentally goes wrong.  Finally, look at your program and see what happens if 0 or 1 is in the input.  You print a message, but then you *still* go into the rest of your loop, which means that even if you reinitialize `X` correctly, you will still start `X` at 2 and then keep increasing it until it equals -1 or 0, which will never happen.  (Actually, it will, due to wraparound, but it will take a long time.)  Also, double-check your logic when `N` is 2.  You will either get the wrong answer or the program will hang.  OK, one other thing: in your inner loop, when you set `IsPrime := false;`, you still go through the rest of your loop, which is a waste of time.  Try instead

```
     IF S = 0 THEN
        IsPrime := False;
        exit;    -- No need to keep looping!
     END IF;
```

Comment: I am changing standard input through ada-guide environment. And yes  it was because I was not re-initializing my X value. Thank you all.